# Twig use specific value for 0 results, 1 result and multiple results

Tags: php, symfony, twig

While working on an article module in Symfony2, I have to display how many times something is read. To make the 'sentence' grammatically correct I used the code below.

This works obvious but it botters me that I can't find a shorter, cleaner way.
Is there something like `article.getReads|length|displayresult('No results', '%d result', '%d results)` available or do I have to make this on my own?

```
{% if article.getReads|length == 0 %}Be the first one to read this!
{% else %}
  {{ article.getReads|length|number_format(0, ',', '.') }} 
  read{% if article.getReads|length != 1 %}s{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the symfony2 pluralization translate component as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#explicit-interval-pluralization).

As example you can declare a file like:

```
#src / Acme / DemoBundle / Resources / translations / messages.en.xliff

            <trans-unit id="11">
                <source>article.read</source>
                <target>{0} No results|{1} one result|[2,Inf] results</target>
            </trans-unit>
```

Ad use it as follow in the twig template:

```
{{ 'article.read'|transchoice(article.getReads|length) }}
```

Hope this help